Why does Explorer keeps restarting but working fine in safe mode?
Why does Explorer keeps restarting but working fine in safe mode?
Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 10.0.22621.4036, time stamp: 0xed8d1c8e
Faulting module name: Taskbar.View.dll, version: 2124.16310.10.0, time stamp: 0x66721a46
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x0000000000471e82
Faulting process id: 0x0xB8C
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1DAF62919BCBF92
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.with
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Core_cw5n1h2txyewy\Taskbar.View.dll
Report Id: 9968f176-3d1e-438f-969e-c143bb8b5c4f
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 


Safe mode does not load a whole lot of stuff such as drivers including the display driver.  Therefore the implication is that one of your device drivers is possibly faulty.
You can start by ensuring that all the drivers are up to date.  Then run SFC
SFC /SCANNOW.
If that doesn't work then update your question with the results.
